# RestKit: How can I send object through post protocol in some key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I want send object through post protocol to server. I use for it RestKit framework.

**so, example:**

```
PData *item = [[PData alloc] init];
item.uri = @"http://google.com";
item.status = @"0";
item.updated = [NSDate date];
item.created = [NSDate date];
item.user_id = @"3";

RKObjectManager *sharedManager = RKObjectManager sharedManager;
[sharedManager postObject:item
                     path:nil
               parameters:nil
                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    [self printPData:mappingResult];

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n == \nERROE = %@",error);

}];
```

How can I push json (which consist data of item) in some key ("data")?

(this data on server I can take from $_POST["data"])

**How can I do request like this?**

```
{
    "data": {
        "created": "2014-03-05 14:49:30",
        "status": "0",
        "updated": "2014-03-05 14:49:30",
        "uri": "http:\/\/google.com",
        "user_id": "3"
    }
}
```

now, I have had only this:

```
{
    "status": "0",
    "updated": "2014-03-05 14:52:17",
    "user_id": "3",
    "uri": "http:\/\/google.com",
    "created": "2014-03-05 14:52:17"
}
```

Comment: What request descriptor, mapping, route have you tried? What did it do wrong?

Comment: I did all good, but json of object pushed in root of $_POST. but I want that json pushed in $_POST["data"]

Comment: Ok, so show your descriptor and mapping so we can correct them. It's probably a key path error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't specified a key path in your request descriptor.  At the moment, somewhere in your code, you'll have something like this:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptor =
    [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                          objectClass:[PData class]
                                          rootKeyPath:nil
                                               method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

You need to change it to:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptor =
    [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                          objectClass:[PData class]
                                          rootKeyPath:@"data"
                                               method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

That way RestKit will know that `PData` objects ought to be mapped to the `data` key path.